# Query to find two consecutive values of column

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table named `events`. It looks like this:

```
id | location_id | type    | date
1  | 123         | success | 2018-01-02
2  | 45          | success | 2018-01-13
3  | 123         | failure | 2018-01-23
4  | 66          | failure | 2018-02-04
5  | 123         | success | 2018-02-06
6  | 66          | failure | 2018-03-04
```

The `type` column can only have two values - 'success' or 'failure'. What I need to accomplish is the following: find each `location_id` for which at least two consecutive entries in the `events` table have `type=failure`. Consecutive when you order the entries by date, that is. In the example above, only `location_id` 66 should be returned because it has two consecutive failures in the `type` column.

The obvious solution is:

```
iterate through location_ids
    get all entries from events table for each location_id, ordered by date
        iterate through the results and return true if we find two consecutive rows with type=failure
```

My problem with this approach: I have several thousand `location_id`s, and each one could have hundreds of entries in the `events` table. This means we could have hundreds of thousands of operations each time this task is performed (which is quite often because its results should be displayed on the homepage of our admin panel).

So I was wondering if someone knows a better solution. I have tried searching for a query to help me out with this but to no avail.

Comment: "What I need to accomplish is the following: find each location_id for which at least two consecutive entries in the events table have type=failure" -> so the expected output based on your example data would return zero records

Comment: @RaymondNijland Yes that's correct. I'll update the data to include a positive result in a minute.

Comment: So in your sample you have no examples of a reportable failure.  Could you clarify a bit? (ie, consecutive by `id` or when grouped by `location_id`)

Comment: @TimMorton Updated the sample data to clarify. Please let me know if clearer now.

Comment: the column id is not a good way of ordering it instead of date? If id is good, the answer is shorter and faster to run.

Comment: @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ I suppose we could order by id if it will increase performance significantly.

Comment: your new example data also doesn't contain valid consecutive dates based of `type=failure`

Comment: @RaymondNijland It does, for location_id=66. Don't forget we are looking for consecutive failures for each location_id separately.

Comment: oh the consecutive values need to be on month instead off day.

Comment: what if 3 consecutive failures? how you will show it in the report? show the last 2 locations? or only one and the last one?

Comment: @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ We just have to show the location_id either way, not the date of the last failure of anything. So 3 failures or more shouldn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

**Create table/insert data**

```
CREATE TABLE events
    (`id` int, `location_id` int, `type` varchar(7), `date` date)
;

INSERT INTO events
    (`id`, `location_id`, `type`, `date`)
VALUES
    (1, 123, 'success', '2018-01-02'),
    (2, 45, 'success', '2018-01-13'),
    (3, 123, 'failure', '2018-01-23'),
    (4, 66, 'failure', '2018-02-04'),
    (5, 123, 'success', '2018-02-06'),
    (6, 66, 'failure', '2018-03-04')
;
```

For this solution i assumed when you said consecutive you are meaning..

1. consecutive month with the same year and same day

   So 
   2018-02-04 
   2018-03-04 
   is a consecutive value
2. consecutive day with the same year and same month

   So 
   2018-02-04 
   2018-02-05 
   is a consecutive value

> We just have to show the location_id either way, not the date of the
>   last failure of anything. So 3 failures or more shouldn't make a
>   difference

The best thing to do is design a query that could atleast match atleast 2 or more distinct date records based on the `location_id` and `type` group with a filter where `type = 'failure'`

**Query**

```
SELECT 
   location_id 
 , type
FROM 
 events 
WHERE
 type = 'failure'
GROUP BY
   location_id 
 , type
HAVING 
  COUNT(DISTINCT date) >= 2
```

**Result**

```
| location_id |    type |
|-------------|---------|
|          66 | failure |
```

see demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/df4679e/56

Now we use INNER JOIN the get all records.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
 events.*
FROM ( 

  SELECT 
     location_id 
   , type
  FROM 
   events 
  WHERE
   type = 'failure'
  GROUP BY
     location_id 
   , type
  HAVING 
    COUNT(DISTINCT date) >= 2
) AS events_grouped

INNER JOIN
 events
ON
   events_grouped.location_id = events.location_id
 AND
   events_grouped.type = events.type
```

**Result**

```
| id | location_id |    type |       date |
|----|-------------|---------|------------|
|  4 |          66 | failure | 2018-02-04 |
|  6 |          66 | failure | 2018-03-04 |
```

Now we need to have access to the next record. Some databases support LEAD for this. 
 But the current production ready MySQL versions doesn't support that 
So we are going to simulate LEAD with a shifting self join.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
   events1.*
 , events2.*
FROM ( 

  SELECT 
     location_id 
   , type
  FROM 
   events 
  WHERE
   type = 'failure'
  GROUP BY
     location_id 
   , type
  HAVING 
    COUNT(DISTINCT date) >= 2
) AS events_grouped

INNER JOIN
 events events1
ON
   events_grouped.location_id = events1.location_id
 AND
   events_grouped.type = events1.type

INNER JOIN 
 events events2
ON
   # shift to have acces to the next record.
     events1.id <> events2.id 
   AND
     events1.date <= events2.date
```

**Result**

```
| id | location_id |    type |       date | id | location_id |    type |       date |
|----|-------------|---------|------------|----|-------------|---------|------------|
|  4 |          66 | failure | 2018-02-04 |  5 |         123 | success | 2018-02-06 |
|  4 |          66 | failure | 2018-02-04 |  6 |          66 | failure | 2018-03-04 |
```

see demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/df4679e/62

You can clearly the records are shifting within the JOIN so we are now able to add the consecutive value check i was talking about.

**Final query**

```
SELECT 
 events1.location_id
FROM ( 

  SELECT 
     location_id 
   , type
  FROM 
   events 
  WHERE
   type = 'failure'
  GROUP BY
     location_id 
   , type
  HAVING 
    COUNT(DISTINCT date) >= 2
) AS events_grouped

INNER JOIN
 events events1
ON
   events_grouped.location_id = events1.location_id
 AND
   events_grouped.type = events1.type

INNER JOIN 
 events events2
ON
   # shift to have acces to the next record.
     events1.id <> events2.id 
   AND
     events1.date <= events2.date
   AND
   (  
     (
       # check consecutive MONTH, YEAR and DAY need to be the same

       # consecutive month with the same year and same day

       # So <br />
       # 2018-02-04 <br />
       # 2018-03-04 <br />
       # is a consecutive value        
       ABS(YEAR(events1.date) - YEAR(events2.date)) = 0
     AND
       ABS(MONTH(events1.date) - MONTH(events2.date)) = 1
     AND
       ABS(DAY(events1.date) - DAY(events2.date)) = 0   
     )
     OR
     (
       # check consecutive DAY, YEAR and MONTH need to be the same

       # consecutive month with the same year and same day

       # So <br />
       # 2018-02-04 <br />
       # 2018-02-05 <br />
       # is a consecutive value 
         ABS(YEAR(events1.date) - YEAR(events2.date)) = 0
       AND
         ABS(MONTH(events1.date) - MONTH(events2.date)) = 0
       AND
         ABS(DAY(events1.date) - DAY(events2.date)) = 1   
     )   
   )
```

**Result**

```
| location_id |
|-------------|
|          66 |
```

see demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/df4679e/65

Comment: Now that's a thing of beauty :)  But I lost you at the very last step.  I didn't interpret "consecutive" to be exactly one month apart; rather, simply as being two failure in a row when grouped by location_id and sorted by date.  Still, +1 for the "shift".  I figured something like that would be necessary but you had this excellent answer up before I had a chance to think much about it.  Great answer!

Comment: @TimMorton I have basically the same comment, and you're correct regarding what is meant by "consecutive". I will accept this answer because it has helped me resolve the issue, but I suggest it should be updated to reflect what "consecutive" actually means.

Comment: @jovan you are talking about two consecutive values (so that's why i've made mine assumption) of the column not about two consecutive records..